# Formula excel find data from first character in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Using Excel formula, how do i find data from first character in a cell

For example: i find data where first character "J"

```
Jhon
James
Smith
```

results :

```
Jhon 
James
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$3)/(LEFT($A$1:$A$3)="J"),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Put in first cell and copy down.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use **AutoFilter** with the *Begins with...* Option

Starting with:

[image]

and then applying the filter will result in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt you must search J from character, and then display the data